# Track a call in progress while starting an application

Tags: android

can we track a call in progress , means a user is in call while starting an application.. can we trace that in android device.. Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with telephony api in android .see this [link](http://androidapps.org.ua/i_sect18_d1e18123.html) its have an example for it.